# How do I clear a cached SQL Server login?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Last week I needed to change the permissions for a stored procedure.  I have two Windows logins - a standard one which is my default, and one with elevated privileges (which I needed for this particular task on this particular server).  In order to complete the task I changed my login by selecting Options on the login screen

[image]

However, this week (my computer having been turned off all weekend) I've logged onto SSMS, selected a different server to which I've connected under my standard credentials.  But every time I try to modify a stored procedure, for example, SSMS seems to think I want to do this using the elevated credentials I used last week (which, on this particular server, are not valid).
How do I persuade SSMS to "forget" these credentials so that I can carry on as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the server and re-add it. You do this from the log in tab, highlight the server and press the deleted key. This will force the credentials cache to be refreshed.

See this article for more information on clearing the cached login by deleting the server and re-adding it https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/17/sql-server-remove-cached-login-from-ssms-connect-dialog-sql-in-sixty-seconds-049/

Its possible you may also need to delete an entry from the Windows Credential Manager.